# How can I make KSP run at half-speed?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In one of Scott Manley's videos (Interstellar Quest I think), I heard him say that he was running the physics of Kerbal Space Program at half-speed so his computer could handle it. He then doubled the speed in post-production.

**How can I halve the simulation speed of Kerbal Space Program**, or any other game for that matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What Scott Manley did was lower the delta time slider in the settings menu. This essentially slows down time in-game so that the game doesn't have to make the physics calculations as quickly, and can devote a little more time to rendering them. It will cause everything to happen more slowly, but will improve your framerate.

[image]